# Is chaining c# to look like jQuery a good idea?

Tags: c#, extension-methods, method-chaining

I'm thinking of using extension methods to chain a c# statement to look like jQuery in teh following:

```
foo foo2 = 
  new foo().Title(foo1.Title)
  .Name(foo1.Name)
  .DoSomeStuff()
  .DoSomeMoreStuff();
```

**Is this a good/bad idea?**

```
public class foo
{
  public string Title {get;set;}
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int Age {get;set;}

  public foo(){} 
}

public static class fooExtension
{
  public static foo Title(this foo source, string title)
  {
    source.Title = title;
    return source;
  }

 //and other extensions
}
```

**Upadate: More explanation as the the "why" I'm considering this.**
I have 2 things going on:

1. I'm getting data from one object and
   using it to set the properties of
   another.
2. I need to perform some
   action on these properties.

So my initial code looked more like

```
foo2.bars = foo1.bars;
foo2.RemoveUnderage();
foo2.NotifyPatronsBarsAreFull();
```

and instead, I thought that it might be more descriptive to write:

```
foo2.bars(foo1.bars).RemoveUnderage().NotifyPatrons();
```

Initializers are great, but they also bundle the properties all together and I wanted the property set to be close to the actions on which I would be taking on them.

Comment: I think it can make it a little cumbersome when using the debugger to step into the method call that you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything wrong with using object initializers instead?

```
new Foo { Title = foo1.Title, Name = foo1.Name }
   .DoSomeStuff()
   .DoSomeMoreStuff();
```

Chaining in general is fine (look at LINQ) but object initializers mean you don't need to add methods which look like properties.

Comment: This still leaves the question as to whether it's a "good idea" (whatever that might mean) to chain function calls like that, or write them in a chainable fashion.

Comment: Not if you're using 3.5+ (which not everyone is), but either way, kinda beside the point, eh?

Comment: @harpo: You don't have to be using .NET 3.5 - just C# 3 or higher. Object initializers don't rely on any framework support.

Comment: Cool... so you're saying C# 3 can compile to CLR 2?  I didn't know that.  (Still all irrelevant to the OP.)

Comment: @harpo: Absolutely. See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Versions.aspx - which badly needs updating for .NET 4...

Comment: My point of chaining vs initializers is that some of the methods are somewhat related to the properties and I'd like to keep those close together, perhaps on the same line. Ex .Title('C# in Depth, 2nd Edition').RemoveEditionFromTitle(). and so on . . .

Comment: @John: I think I'd suggest using properties and initializers where possible, but use methods for "extras" then.

Answer (score 0):

I personally like this 'fluent' style of programming. Properly-named methods can look like sentences. I would change yours just a bit:

```
foo foo2 = new foo()
{
    Title = foo1.Title,
    Name = foo1.Name
}
.DoSomeStuff()
.DoSomeMoreStuff();
```

Comment: The key to fluent interfaces is that each additional call must build off of the previous result in some useful way.  Simply chaining calls to the same object only saves you from writing "foo2" each time, while complicating the code base.

Comment: @Chris: That's not the only effect. It allows a single *expression* to be computed from several calls. There are several places where that's quite a significant difference.

Comment: @Jon: That was what I meant by "build from previous results".  In contrast, only returing "this" from every method (as seems to be suggested by the example) is a shortcut only.

Comment: @Chris: No, you mistake my meaning. Even if it only returns `this`, you can still use for things like static variable initializers etc where using an extra variable isn't an option (you'd have to use a static constructor, or call a helper method which just did all the initialization). That's one the benefits of object initializers as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a bad idea in terms of readability, but that's strictly a personal thing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean [Fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)? In some cases the same way is used in classes in .NET Framework (i.e. StringBuilder or LINQ extension methods). However the fluent interface must be explicitly created and it is a lot of work and usage from another language than C# can be not so pretty. I don't think that creating fluent interface for every class is good way how deliver good software in short time.